# Reduce UIButton label font size for third line

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, ios7, uilabel

I have a button with changing text in it.

I want if the button text goes for third line it should reduce its font to minimumScaleFactor.
I am using this code

```
self.option1Button.titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = .7;
self.option1Button.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
self.option1Button.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = TRUE;
```

But this is not working. it doesn't change the font size when text reaches to third line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The adjustToFit will only work for single line labels.

Try doing [this](http://www.11pixel.com/blog/28/resize-multi-line-text-to-fit-uilabel-on-iphone/):

```
//Create a string with the text we want to display.
self.ourText = @"This is your variable-length string. Assign it any way you want!";

/* This is where we define the ideal font that the Label wants to use.
Use the font you want to use and the largest font size you want to use. */
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:28];

int i;
/* Time to calculate the needed font size.
This for loop starts at the largest font size, and decreases by two point sizes (i=i-2)
Until it either hits a size that will fit or hits the minimum size we want to allow (i > 10) */
for(i = 28; i > 10; i=i-2) {
    // Set the new font size.
    font = [font fontWithSize:i];
    // You can log the size you're trying: NSLog(@"Trying size: %u", i);

    /* This step is important: We make a constraint box 
    using only the fixed WIDTH of the UILabel. The height will
    be checked later. */ 
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(260.0f, MAXFLOAT);

    // This step checks how tall the label would be with the desired font.
    CGSize labelSize = [self.ourText sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    /* Here is where you use the height requirement!
    Set the value in the if statement to the height of your UILabel
    If the label fits into your required height, it will break the loop
    and use that font size. */
    if(labelSize.height <= 180.0f)
        break;
}
// You can see what size the function is using by outputting: NSLog(@"Best size is: %u", i);

// Set the UILabel's font to the newly adjusted font.
msg.font = font;

// Put the text into the UILabel outlet variable.
msg.text = self.ourText;
```

Comment: For some reasons, I am using fontSize and height in Interface Builder So this will not work on my side.

Comment: @AzkaarAli You have to do some of this in code. Your requirement cannot be satisfied in interface builder, I think. Also, the above `sizeWithFont` has been replaced with a new function in iOS 7 (`boundingRectWithSize`).

Answer (score 1):

If you want your button to display three lines, you will have to set `numberOfLines` to 3. Strange but true.

Comment: No, I only want 2 lines, if the text is more than 2 line, it should reduce font size to fit in 2 lines.